# Can't get Galaxy S3 to work with Win7/Win8 computers

Tags: galaxy-s3

When I connect my S3 to my laptops (the same behavior on both, one running Win 7, the other Win 8) I get the bee-beep sound, the device appears among found devices **but** after a few seconds, it disappears. Then it continues with upwards and downwards bee-beeping which by itself is hugely annoying.

I've tried removing the device and adding it again, installing/reinstalling Samsung Kies, updating the drivers etc.

After a while, the bee-beeping stops, until the device get a call or something like that (or even nothing seemingly).

I have no other clues what to do. As far I can see it's something with MTP-part of my device. Didn't bring me much joy, that information, though... :)

1. What is it caused by?
2. How do I kill it?

EDIT

It's the original cable, directly from the box. I've also tried a different one (a friend of mine had one). Phone has been restarted, too.

The strange part is that it's only two of the four devices that gets installed wrongly - *MTP USB Device* and *Samsung Mobile MTP Device*, while *Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2* and *Samsung Mobile USB Modem #2* are installed just fine. What's up with the #2's, by the way?

Comment: Does it behave the same when plugged into a different computer?  How about different USB ports?

Comment: @techie007 I've tested it on two different computers (different OSs as well). Different USB ports on each of the machines too. The behavior of bee-beep remains and irritates the waste products out of me...

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to a cabling defect, if you've already re-installed drivers/software. Try with another cable. If that doesn't help, restart your phone.

To ensure a correct driver installation, do the following:

1. Disconnect your phone from the computer
2. On your PC, [open device manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Device-Manager).
3. Remove everything that has to do with your Samsung phone. That is, right click it and select **uninstall...**
4. Reboot PC*
5. Re-install every piece of software or drivers from Samsung **before reconnecting your phone.**
6. Reboot PC*
7. Connect samsung device and let Windows configure the drivers.

* Rebooting may not be necessary but it's the safest way when dealing with drivers.

Comment: It's the original cable, directly from the box. I've also tried a different one (a friend of mine had one). Phone has been restarted, too. The strange part is that it's only two of the four devices that gets installed wrongly - *MTP USB Device* and *Samsung Mobile MTP Device*, while *Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2* and *Samsung Mobile USB Modem #2* are installed just fine. What's up with the #2's, by the way?

Comment: @KonradViltersten please see my edit.